# An elegant way to pass derived type to base member template function?

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class, base-class

I have a class called 'ValueChecker'

which has the following member function:

```
template<typename T>
bool ValueChecker::checkMe( std::ostringstream &oss, T &me) { 
   std::cout << "Default checkMe() for " << typeid(me).name() << std::endl; 
   return true;
}
```

The class ValueChecker is intended to do some simple checks on the values of derived class.  checkMe() will eventually get specialized for the different derived classes:

```
class Airplane : public ValueChecker {
   friend class ValueChecker;
   [...]
}


template<>
bool ValueChecker::checkMe<Airplane>( std::ostringstream &oss, Airplane &me) { 
   ...    
   /* Actually, this code is generated from a simple file which translates
    * a simple language into C++ code.  So that a non-developer can write
    * the simple checks.
    *
    * ValueChecker itself has utility functions that may be called in the
    * template specialization which are shared across all types.
    */

}
```

This works, but there's just a small problem with the declaration of checkMe, when you look at the invocation:

```
int main() {
  Airplane plane;
  std::ostringstream oss;

  if( plane.checkMe( oss, plane)) {
    cout << "Values are bogus!  " << oss.str() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I call plane.checkMe(oss,plane).  But, I could just as well pass another Airplane and not check plane.  Furthermore, the invocation is redundant?  Meaning, theoretically, the compiler should know which template function to call based on the plane's type.  There shouldn't be a need to pass it in as an argument too?  Anyways, it would be nice not to eliminate the last argument.  So a call like this would be nice:

```
if( plane.checkMe(oss)) { ... }  // Calls the right template specialization.
```

I just can't get it to work.  Can the C++ guru's here help me out?  thanks.

Comment: Can't we pass this pointer in typeid?

Comment: Did you evaluate CRTP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: That seems like rather odd design in the first place. Why is `Airplane` derived from `ValueChecker`? Why does `checkMe()` take an argument of type `T` when (judging from your question) it's supposed to only check `this`?

Answer (score 4):

For your given code, you don't really need to use either `template` or `friend`. Instead use inheritance, and make the `checkMe()` method as `protected` and  `virtual` method. Then override the `checkMe()` method in the derived class. If you do not need a default implementation, you could as well make it pure virtual. Here's a quick code snippet based on your example. (Note the use of `this` pointer.)

```
class ValueChecker {
protected:
    virtual bool checkMe() { 
        std::cout << "Default checkMe() for " << typeid(this).name() << std::endl; 
        return true;
    }
};

class Airplane : public ValueChecker {
public:    
    virtual bool checkMe() {
        std::cout << "Airplane checkMe() for " << typeid(this).name() << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
  Airplane plane;
  plane.checkMe();
}
```

You would need a default implementation when there's some "common" logic you want to use in one or more derived classes, in addition to the logic specific to the derived class itself. In that case, use the scope resolution operator to access the base class's logic.

```
    bool Airplane::checkMe() {
        std::cout << "Airplane checkMe() for " << typeid(this).name() << std::endl;

        // use the "common" logic from the base class (if required)
        ValueChecker::checkMe();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @Bitdiot If your query has been addressed, could you please upvote answers and accept an answer? (I would prefer mine :) )

Answer (score 3):

You might want to implement this as a pure virtual method.

```
class ValueChecker
{
public:
    virtual bool checkMe(std::ostringstream& oss) = 0;
};

class Airplane : public ValueChecker
{
public:
    virtual bool checkMe(std::ostringstream& oss);
};
```

That way you can just call `plane.checkMe(oss)` and the checkMe-Method of airplane will be called.

Answer (score 0):

There's a common trick that is often done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern
that could do the trick for you.

Comment: CRTP is not really required here. There's an easier solution, although I agree the way its implemented in the question, it does look like one for CRTP.